# Differing-Size Binary Edits

Tags: assembly

What are the general techniques/methods used for making static changes to a binary file where the length of the edited bytes is larger or smaller than the original? Obviously such a change would mess up the offsets.

e.g. Say I have the byte sequence `4F 3E 23` and wish to change it to `23 56 7E 74 21`

Comment: See http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8149/adding-instructions-in-ida

Comment: @8BitAce: Well, it would mean that you have a perfect disassembler that can rebuild the whole semantics of the program and recompute the new offsets. This is impossible in the general case...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have two options:

- search for some free, unused space in the executable, put your code
  there, and put a JMP wherever you originally wanted to insert more
  instructions. (this would probably involve changing the permissions so the code can be executed without access violations)
- instead of static patching, inject a DLL and put a JMP to your code contained in the DLL.

In both cases, you'd need to preserve the program state
   (probably a PUSHAD then POPAD when you're done), then JMP back
   and resume execution.

An example (second approach, assuming MSVC):

```
void __declspec(naked) MyCode()
{
    __asm PUSHAD
    //your code here
    __asm POPAD
    __asm PUSH returnAddress
    __asm RETN
}
```

and to patch it:

```
DWORD AddrToPatch = 0xC0DE;

DWORD RelAddr = (DWORD)(MyCode - (DWORD)AddrToPatch) - 5;
*AddrToPatch = 0xE9;
*((DWORD *)(AddrToPatch + 0x1)) = RelAddr;
```

Honestly, I think you're better off doing it like that - the first method is a lot more hassle, and injecting a DLL is fairly easy, you can automate that by playing around with the IAT or TLS callbacks.

Comment: The first method was what I was seeing the most suggestions for. The second seems much more robust. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a length of the edited bytes that is smaller than the original use the NOP NOP NOPs to fill in the gaps