# Is it possible to get back to a compilable form of source code using IDA pro

Tags: ida, disassembly, c++

I am familiar with debuggers and sorts. I was going through a program and noticed that IDA does make some mistakes on what it decides what on its pseudo code will be.

Is there a list of common mistakes by IDA and do you think that it would be possible to get something to a compilable source?

I thought I would test it out on some programs and one thing weird I noticed is that it will do:

```
v1 = thiscall();
```

Where as in source I just have the `thiscall();`.

I also noticed that it bloats a lot of things which is from the assembly itself.

So my questions are:

- Is there a list of common IDA mistakes ?
- Can once I have worked back fairly close to source will IDA produce a header file ?
- Is it possible to get back to a source that I could at least compile code from?

Its looking like I might be able to providing if I knew the libraries and outline of the program well. Let me know what your thoughts and experiences from using IDA on this subject.

**Edit:**
I found a project that actually did this. All functions are byte for byte in 100% accuracy. So yes my past self, it is indeed possible.
https://github.com/diasurgical/devilution

Comment: Regarding your edit, it is possible, but theoretical results show that it's not possible to write an automated tool that does it in all cases. I touched on why in my answer here: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311/why-are-machine-code-decompilers-less-capable-than-for-example-those-for-the-clr/312#312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get anything back that compiles, or even assembles, without *massive* manual intervention, and, given the ambiguities in object code, it's very unlikely this situation will ever change.

See [Why there are not any disassemblers that can generate re-assemblable asm code?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/why-there-are-not-any-disassemblers-that-can-generate-re-assemblable-asm-code) for a more detailed answer.